# Breadboard setup for a data acquisition system trigger

Tags: power-supply

Does anyone know what the best way of getting from a variable input of either 110v or 220v and using just a standard breadboard (solder type) and getting down to a 5v output.  Please let me know if I need to be more clear.  This is fairly new to me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to go from 110V/220V to 5V? Is your input AC? Is your output DC?

Comment: @bjthom : when was the last time you used 220 V DC ?

Comment: I am using a data acquisition program and this is going to be a trigger type device for the program and I need an output of 5v.  It is A/C input.

Comment: "using just a standard breadboard": so my first thought of using a small transformer + rectifier + linear regulator (all things you might find in your spare parts box) would not fit the requirement ;__;

Answer (score 2):

The make line direct switched mode 5W power supplies. Best bet is used an old PC power supply. the white 4 pin Molex connects have readily avail outputs.

1. 12V
2. gnd
3. gnd
4. 5V

Comment: I wouldn't use an old PC power supply. Some require minimal load or they will not turn on or even sporadically fail. Getting an AC mains voltage down to low-voltage DC, isolated from mains, is also called an 'adapter'. Quite a novel invention :-)

Comment: 10% preload is standard on the old PSU's. and they are free.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how much power you need.

Anyway, the easiest way to a universal (85 - 265 V AC input) supply for PCB or breadboard mount is one of [these](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/606238.pdf):

[image: switcher]

It contains the same switcher as used in a wall-wart, but then for PCB mount. Compact (32 mm x 27 mm) and for 5 V output exists in a 2.75 W and a 4.5 W version.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern switched-mode Power supply will do the trick. They usually have an input range from 90 to 260 VAC and are available at pretty low prices.
Example:
http://nl.farnell.com/xp-power/vcp05us05/psu-ac-dc-5-w-pcb-mount-5v-1a/dp/1716962

Also most consumer equipment contains something like this so it's worth trying to find any old CD/DVD player or a printer and take it from that.